# Disable windows sbs2008 updates via GPO

Tags: group-policy, windows-sbs-2008, windows-update

I have a windows sbs2008 server and i would like to stop widnows updates from being downloaded via a group policy i have managed to fidn the policy then when i clicked update it took me to a different window called gpo management editor and i cannot seem to find the option in there to disable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look under `[Computer/Administrative templates/windows components/Windows Update]`

Comment: Thanks but that doesnt allow you to stop the server downloading windows updates

Comment: Look at the Configure Windows Update setting